# Duplicate one element's event handlers onto another?

Tags: jquery, events

**How do you copy an event handler from one element to another?** For example:

```
$('#firstEl')
    .click(function() {
        alert("Handled!");
    })
;

// here's where the magic happens 
$('#secondEl').click = $('#firstEl').click; // ????
```

Note that the second element is being processed at a different time to when the first element is getting its handler, meaning that this:

```
$('#firstEl, #secondEl').click(function() { ... });
```

...won't work.

Comment: Sadly none of the answers show it without using jQuery.

Comment: @ShaneReustle it's a question about jQuery events...

Comment: Which in the background work just like normal events. I was hoping to see how to do this without using jQuery on standard JS events.

Comment: @ShaneReustle Same for me... I guess I will google some more, otherwise I'll post a JavaScript answer

Answer (score 24):

This question was already answered but for future reference: you could copy them by iterating the events of the original element and binding their handlers to the target.

**> see edit below!**

```
// iterate event types of original
$.each($('#original').data('events'), function() {
  // iterate registered handler of original
  $.each(this, function() {
    $('#target').bind(this.type, this.handler);
  });
});
```

This is handy when you have no control of the original element (e.g. when using a plugin) and just want to clone the behavior of a certain element.

**Edit:** Access to an elements event handlers has been changed in later jQuery versions. This should work for newer versions:

```
$.each($._data($('#original').get(0), 'events'), function() {
  // iterate registered handler of original
  $.each(this, function() {
    $('#target').bind(this.type, this.handler);
  });
});
```

Cheers

Comment: Using the `triggerHandler()` JQuery method is a better solution. @KenBrowing has an answer on that below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/442305/1988326

Comment: @Chris: Thank you for the edit. After searching for days for a solution to save events and handle them later, this is the only place i found where the access to the event handlers of jquery is described. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't easily (and probably shouldn't) "copy" the event.  What you can do is use the same function to handle each:

```
var clickHandler = function() { alert('click'); };
// or just function clickHandler() { alert('click'); };

$('#firstEl').click(clickHandler);

// and later
$('#secondEl').click(clickHandler);
```

Alternatively you could actually fire the event for the first element in the second handler:

```
$('#firstEl').click(function() {
    alert('click');
});

$('secondEl').click(function() {
    $('#firstEl').click();
});
```

Edit: @nickf is worried about polluting the global namespace, but this can almost always be avoided by wrapping code in an object:

```
function SomeObject() {
    this.clickHandler = function() { alert('click'); };
}
SomeObject.prototype.initFirstEvent = function() {
    $('#firstEl').click(this.clickHandler);
};
SomeObject.prototype.initSecondEvent = function() {
    $('#secondEl').click(this.clickHandler);
};
```

or wrapping your code in an anonymous function and calling it immediately:

```
(function() {
    var clickHandler = function() { alert('click'); };
    $('#firstEl').click(clickHandler);
    $('#secondEl').click(clickHandler);
})();
```

Comment: ah yes that would work, but I was hoping for a method which wouldn't pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the [triggerHandler method](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/triggerHandler)

```
// here's where the magic happens 
//$('#secondEl').click = $('#firstEl').click; // ????
$('#secondEl').click(function() {
    $('#firstEl').triggerHandler('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var clickHandler = function() { alert("Handled!"); }
$('#firstEl').click(clickHandler);
$('#secondEl').click(clickHandler);
```

Answer (score -2):

http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/01/copy-events-from-one-element-to-another

Answer (score -3):

$('#secondEl').click = $('#firstEl').click.bind($('#secondEl'));

Assuming you are using Prototype JS (http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind)